# how to overwrite list with appended element, in original order and without extra symbols

Tags: python-3.x

how to overwrite list with appended element, in original order and without extra symbols, each time I've add new word to document

```
Extend list:  [['\n', '1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '4\n'], '4', '\n\n', 'X']
Append list:  [['\n', '1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '4\n'], ['\n\n', 'X']]
```

how to write it just like this

```
1 
2 
3 
4

X
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this function to join both the list. Here i am cleaning both the list of those characters and also flattening the list into a single list. Then i am just maintaining unique appearances.

```
import itertools

def join_list( list1 , list2 ):
    list1 = list(chain(*list1))
    list1 = [i.replace('\n', '') for i in list1]
    list1 = [i for i in list1 if i != '']
    #list1 = list(set(list1))
    list2 = list(chain(*list2))
    list2 = [i.replace('\n', '') for i in list2]
    list2 = [i for i in list2 if i != '']
    #list2 = list(set(list2))
    result = list(set(list1 + list2))
    return result
```

I hope this works for you..

Comment: hi where can I get itertools? I'm on windows 10-64bit python 3.5